# Importing Excel to SQL Database using vb.net and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Im currently building a project that lets users import Excel files via a web interface (built), which saves the file to the server (built), and then imports the data into the SQL Database on the server depending on a few of the user options (not built).

Im not familiar with SQL database tools within VS at all so I have been fumbling around for the better part of two days just trying to get everything set up. Im pretty sure I need to use BulkCopy, but Im not quite sure how to use it and I can't seem to find specific examples that explain it pertaining to my specific application.

So in my App_Data folder I have an .mdf title "Device Database." In that database I have three tables: "Galaxy Nexus", "Hercules" , and "Ruby"

I am trying to import four cells from each imported excel sheet to their respective tables.

I would like to import cell(2,2) to column1 in the table, cell(2,3) to column2, cell(3,2) to column3 and cell(1,1) to column4.

The code I am trying to accomplish this with is:

```
    Dim ExcelContentType As String = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Dim Excel2010ContentType As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Dim excelConnectionString As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", SavedFile)
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
        Dim Command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection)
        connection.Open()
        Using reader As DbDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim sqlConnectionString As String = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ExcelDB;Integrated Security=True"
            Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString)
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = DropDown1.SelectedItem.ToString
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Where I am having trouble is, I do not know how to select certain cells from the excel sheet to import and I do not know how to copy those cells to specific columns in the specified table.

Any and all help is always appreciated.
Thanks,
Zach

Comment: I use the Excel COM libraries.  Then you can just write insert and/or update queries (or use stored procedures).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I use the COM libraries too when I am automating excel scripts or transferring excel to excel. Can you work with SQL Databases like excel? Can I go NexusGaxaxyTable.column1(or whatever) = XLSheet1.Cells(2,2).Value.ToString, once both are open?

Comment: I don't think so.  I usually just craft an insert or update query.  You would have to work with t-sql.  For example, get the value in the cell and use that to update the table:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: I can post sample code in c# if you like.

Comment: That would be really helpful. Could you post a few comments on it too so I can translate it to VB.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im posting an answer so that if anyone else stumbles upon this, they might be helped as well.

This is what got everything to work for me. (Shout out to kevin)

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim appPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
        Dim con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & appPath & "App_Data\Devicedatabase.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"
        con.Open()
        MsgBox("open")
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("close")
    End Sub
```

This got the connection open after much trying and frustration.

This got the excel values imported to the database:

```
 Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With
{
    .ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & appPath & "App_Data\Devicedatabase.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"
}
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With
    {
        .Connection = con,
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & """" & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString & """" & "ColumnName1, ColumnName2)VALUES (@Col1,@Col2)"
    }
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@Col1"})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@Col2"})
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = "Value obtained from Excel"
    cmd.Parameters(1).Value = "Value obtained from Excel"
    con.Open()
    Dim Result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    If Result <> 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert failed.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Row inserted.")
    End If

End Using
End Using
```

Enjoy guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) dll for this. It will read the excel file and give the Dataset as result.

Comment: ExcelDataReader will give a set of DataTables inside Dataset. There are nothing but each work sheet. Definitely good stuff !!

Comment: Im kinda confused about this. I see that it can read the data from an Excel sheet and export it into a data set fairly easily, but how do you put that dataset into a SQL table? More specifically, how would you take a few cells out of excel and put them into specific columns in the SQL table?

Comment: That you have to write a code for filtering the columns from DataSet and then code for Database update. The component will give only DataSet.

Comment: Im sure I can figure out the dataset part, would you happen to know the code to add values to a particular column in a specific table? I'm struggling to find a way to open a database and add information to it.

Answer (score 0):

simple code for 'abcConnectionString' as a connection string
and 'pqr_table' as sql table.
'Sheet1' is for the sheet1 of excel file.
important thing is the table format ie rows n columns of excel n database file should b same

her is the vb.net code foe veb application
one FileUpload with name 'FileUpload1'
and one button.
this code is in side the buton method

```
Dim excelConnectionString As String = String.Empty
Dim uploadPath As String = "~/Uploads/"
Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath(uploadPath + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
Dim strConnection As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("abcConnectionString").ConnectionString
If fileExt = ".xls" OrElse fileExt = "XLS" Then
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" & filePath & "'" & "; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"
ElseIf fileExt = ".xlsx" OrElse fileExt = "XLSX" Then
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False"
End If
Dim excelConnection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection)
excelConnection.Open()
Dim dReader As OleDbDataReader
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(strConnection)
sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "pqr_table"
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader)
MsgBox("Congratulations! Successfully Imported.")
        excelConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

simple code for 'abcConnectionString' as a connection string and 'pqr_table' as sql table. 'Sheet1' is for the sheet1 of excel file. important thing is the table format ie rows n columns of excel n database file should b same

here is the vb.net code foe veb application one FileUpload with name 'FileUpload1' and one button. this code is in side the buton method

```
Dim excelConnectionString As String = String.Empty     
Dim uploadPath As String = "~/Uploads/" 
Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath(uploadPath + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

Dim strConnection As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("abcConnectionString").ConnectionString

If fileExt = ".xls" OrElse fileExt = "XLS" Then
    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" & filePath & "'" & "; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"
ElseIf fileExt = ".xlsx" OrElse fileExt = "XLSX" Then
    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False"
End If
Dim excelConnection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection)
excelConnection.Open()
Dim dReader As OleDbDataReader
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(strConnection)
sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "pqr_table"
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader)
MsgBox("Congratulations! Successfully Imported.")
excelConnection.Close()
```