# Reading data from Excel file using Epplus and load it to SQL server

Tags: .net, epplus

I am new to .net and epplus. I have task to read an excel file and upload it to SQLserver. Not all the data from the excel file. Only few columns and rows that should be mapped into SQL table.

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)

        {

            try

            {

                string FilePath = string.Concat("~path" + FileUpload1.FileName);

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);

                FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);

                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
                {

                    //get the first worksheet in the workbook
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
                    int i = 2;
                    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                        {

                                Console.WriteLine(" Row:" + row + " column:" + col + " Value:" + worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim());
                          }
                    }



                }


            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                Label1 = ex.Message;

            }

        }

    }
```

and the aspx page is

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />  


    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />

</div>.
```

Can someone suggest whether this is the right approach and also piece of code to read the data to sql server.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670983/import-data-from-an-excel-sheet-into-a-sql-server-database might be useful. You should choose how to write to the database - via ADO level or Daaper/Entity Framework abstractions. Apart from that referenced answer should help